# CSS - need to arrange this img layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been struggling to arrange this layout of images.
I've been thinking of using flexbox and i'm pretty sure it's doable with it but I can't manage to find the right way to do it.
If anyone is able to help me i'll be glad.
Here is the layout with each square being an img in a link tag :

[img layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2gLG.jpg)

The space between each img must be the same, that's why I've been thinking of using flexbox.

Thanks in advance, 
j

Edit: I uploaded what I've been working on :
http://163.172.185.65/flexboxuse.html

Comment: I think issue is that you have not even tried to do something.

Comment: Show some code of what you tried

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! This might help you get started with flexbox https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7EIAgfkhmg

Comment: I'm currently uploading what I did because someone's suggesting I didn't even try. 
I'm quite used to flexbox and I'm not sure I need to get started with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a working example using flex and percentage width:

```css
html,body{
                border:0;
                margin:0;
                height:100%;
            }
            #wrap
            {
                width:300px;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: space-between;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #container
            {
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:row;
                flex-wrap:wrap;
                justify-content:space-between;
                height:70%;
            }
            #green
            {
                background-color:chartreuse;
                width:30%;
                order:0;
            }
            #red
            {
                background-color:red;
                height:48%;
            }
            #blue
            {
                background-color:blue;
                height:48%;            
            } 
            #yellow
            {
                background-color:yellow;
                height:49%;                
            }   
            #aquamarine
            {
                background-color:aqua;
                height:49%;
            }
            #purple
            {
                background-color:purple;
                height:28%;
            }
            .col
            {
                width:32%;
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:column;
                justify-content:space-between;
            }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
            <div id="container">
                <div id="green"></div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div id="red"></div>
                    <div id="yellow"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div id="blue"></div>
                    <div id="aquamarine"></div> 
                </div>                                             
            </div>
            <div id="purple"></div>        
        </div>
```

Comment: you should be more specific what caused the error or at least what exactly is the solution.

Comment: Fixed an issue. Now snippet runs successfully.

Comment: I managed to get an acceptable result using this snippet, thanks a lot. Just had to add a 3% margin top on purple div.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this with flexbox, but even just `float:left` will do the trick.

**Working Example:**

```css
section {
width: 312px;
}

div {
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 0 6px 6px 0;
background-color: gray;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
height: 206px;
}

div:nth-of-type(6) {
width: 312px;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

div:nth-of-type(3),
div:nth-of-type(5),
div:nth-of-type(6) {
margin-right: 0;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
background-color: lime;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
background-color: red;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
background-color: blue;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
background-color: yellow;
}

div:nth-of-type(5) {
background-color: cyan;
}

div:nth-of-type(6) {
background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>
```

---

**Second approach** *(this time with element heights relative to the height of the viewport)*

```css
section {
width: calc(100vh + 12px);
}

div {
float: left;
width: 33vh;
height: 33vh;
margin: 0 6px 6px 0;
background-color: gray;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
height: calc(66vh + 6px);
}

div:nth-of-type(6) {
width: calc(100vh + 12px);
margin-bottom: 0;
}

div:nth-of-type(3),
div:nth-of-type(5),
div:nth-of-type(6) {
margin-right: 0;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
background-color: lime;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
background-color: red;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
background-color: blue;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
background-color: yellow;
}

div:nth-of-type(5) {
background-color: cyan;
}

div:nth-of-type(6) {
background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm actually resizing my images using percentage size and your solution can't actually work with my design, i can't fix height of elements using pixels because it needs to be sized according to the viewport.

If you have any clue on how to do this with flexbox, i'll be glad.
Thank you anyway for your quick answer, I appreciate.

Comment: Wrapping doesn't work the same way in flexbox as it does with floats. If you try to use flexbox, you will have to put the four squares in a container. Flexbox is usually more capable than floats, but in this case it isn't. Why not use the viewport-height-relative `vh` as your unit of length instead of `px`? (See the second approach in the post above).

Comment: Yes, i've been using multiple flex container to get a reasonable result.
I might try your solution using viewport units, I didn't think about that.
Thanks for your time, i'll keep you informed.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox example with percentage:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.sidebar {
  background: limegreen;
  height: 70%;
  width: 30%;
}
.rightCont {
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  height: calc(50% - 10px);
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
  height: calc(50% - 10px);
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  height: 50%;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.sky {
  background: cyan;
  height: 50%;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.bottom {
  background: violet;
  height: calc(30% - 10px);
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="rightCont">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
    <div class="sky"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```